# Where best to put comment box

Tags: website-design, accessibility, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should you place the “add a comment” form above or below the list of comments?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/should-you-place-the-add-a-comment-form-above-or-below-the-list-of-comments)

Where would you regard as the best place to put a comment box? Immediately after the article or after the article and comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a possibility I prefer a other choice:

- a comment box after article for comment it;
- the possibility to reply directly to a comment for increase the engagment (and discussion) to the site.